# how to create foreach with this value array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

i have array strings variable like this

```
$qtybuy = array('233','235');
$dede = array('test1','test2');
$all = array('exchange' => $dede , 'sell' => $qtybuy);
```

and if i execute with print_r($all)
i got this code

```
Array
(
    [exchange] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1
            [1] => test2
        )

    [sell] => Array
        (
            [0] => 233
            [1] => 235
        )

)
```

and my problem is i want to get array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [exchange] => test1
            [sell] => 233
        
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [exchange] => test2
            [sell] => 235
 
        )



)
```

maybe must use a foreach or loop but i dont know how to change array object with foreach or loop .. maybe someone can help me. and sorry for my bad english..

thanks

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Creating the classes? Filling the classes?

Comment: Arrays can be cast to objects and vice versa. It's only a matter of organizing your data the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$qtybuy = array('233','235');
$dede = array('test1','test2');

$new = [];

foreach ($qtybuy as $key => $value) {
    $new[] = (object)[
        'exchange' => $dede[$key],
        'sell' => $qtybuy[$key]
    ]; 
}

var_dump($new);
```

As you can see, you can just cast to object :)

Comment: The `$all` array becomes unnecessary, I suggest you remove it from the answer so it doesn't confuse some beginner that comes across this in the future.

Comment: @El_Vanja Forgot it. Thanks for the reminder.